# How can I convert UTC HH:MM(no date) to local time based off of a time zone while taking into account DST?

Tags: python

I am writing a program that I want to display the local departure time of a flight(stored in UTC). I am trying to find a function that will convert UTC to local time while taking in to account DST. I looked at pytz and tried this:

```
timezone_narita = pytz.timezone('Asia/Tokyo') 
time_zulu = datetime.time(13, 45)
local_time = timezone_narita.fromutc(time_zulu)
print(local_time)
```

But it didn't like me using datetime.time. Any suggestions or ideas?

Comment: Please share your input and expected output

Comment: time_zulu = datetime.time(13, 45) is essentially my input and the output would be 22:45 since JST is +9